# lightshow project

Tags: code-review, wires

[image]

Hello guys. I'm working on a little lightshow that has 3 extra feature's when i press the button. depending on the variable counter the lights should do something and it should message you that you found a feature. But my project does'nt work. it compiles fine on the tinkercad site but not everything works. The lights itself work but the button feature's dont. I don't know if my code is wrong or the wiring since its able to compile.

I expected that if i press the countbutton it counts up and when it reaches 6 it does the code in the if statement. However when i press the count up and or count down button according to the variable it needs to reach it doesn't do anything.

the code:

```
int time = 250;
int ledpins[] = {3, 6, 7, 4, 2, 5};
int amount = 6;
int countup = 11;
int countdown = 12;
int counter;
int timepressed = 4000;
float timerpressed = 0;


void setup()
{
  for (int pin = 0; pin < aantal; pin++)
    {pinMode(ledpins[pin], OUTPUT);}
   //alle leds worden door middel van de loop gedefinieerd als output
   //pin is eerst 0 dat is element 3 in de array. de counter heeft einde
   //nog niet en gaat verder tot de conditie bereikt is
   pinMode(countdown, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(countup, INPUT);
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  bool plus = digitalRead(countup);
  bool minus = digitalRead(countdown);
  delay(20);

  if (plus == LOW){
    counter++;
   if (counter > 10) counter = 0;
  }

  if (minus == LOW){
    counter--;
  }

//Easter egg nummer 1. 2 lights on.
if (counter == -2){
    digitalWrite(ledpins[1], HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledpins[4], HIGH);
    Serial.print("Gefeliciteerd je hebt (1/3) easter egg gevonden!");
}
//Easter egg nummer 2. all lights off.
else if (counter == 6){
  digitalWrite(ledpins[0], LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledpins[1], LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledpins[2], LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledpins[3], LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledpins[4], LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledpins[5], LOW);
  Serial.print("Gefeliciteerd je hebt (2/3) easter egg gevonden!");
}
//Easter egg nummer 3. blink alternately after keeping the button pressed for 4 seconds.
else if (timerpressed >= timepressed){
  digitalWrite(ledpins[0], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledpins[1], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledpins[4], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledpins[5], HIGH);
  Serial.print("Gefeliciteerd je hebt (3/3) easter egg gevonden!");
 }
```

---

Okay an update on this post is a was able to make a couple of fixes. My code was keep getting stuck in the array loop for the leds. I've made it that it now only goes trough it once. Another thing i fixed was the wiring of the buttons since this wasnt correct. The only feature that isnt working right now is the keep the button pressed feature.
[image]

```
int tijd = 250;
int ledpins[] = {3, 6, 7, 4, 2, 5};
int aantal = 6;
int knopplus = 11;
int knopmin = 12;
int teller;
int indruktijd = 4000;
float timerdruktijd = 0;
int pin = 0;
int pin1 = 0;

void setup()
{
  for (int pin = 0; pin < aantal; pin++)
    {pinMode(ledpins[pin], OUTPUT);}
   //alle leds worden door middel van de loop gedefinieerd als output
   //pin is eerst 0 dat is element 3 in de array. de counter heeft einde
   //nog niet en gaat verder tot de conditie bereikt is
   pinMode(knopmin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(knopplus, INPUT);
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  bool plus = digitalRead(knopplus);
  bool minus = digitalRead(knopmin);
  delay(20);

  if (plus == LOW){
    teller++;
   if (teller > 10) teller = 0;
  }

  if (minus == LOW){
    teller--;
  }

//Easter egg nummer 1. twee lichten aan.
if (teller == -2){
    digitalWrite(ledpins[1], HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledpins[4], HIGH);
    Serial.print("Gefeliciteerd je hebt (1/3) easter egg gevonden!");
}
//Easter egg nummer 2. alle lichten uit.
else if (teller == 6){
  digitalWrite(ledpins[0], LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledpins[1], LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledpins[2], LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledpins[3], LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledpins[4], LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledpins[5], LOW);
  Serial.print("Gefeliciteerd je hebt (2/3) easter egg gevonden!");
}
//Easter egg nummer 3. knipper om en om na 4 seconden lang de -knop ingedrukt te houden
else if (timerdruktijd >= indruktijd){
  digitalWrite(ledpins[0], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledpins[1], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledpins[4], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledpins[5], HIGH);
  Serial.print("Gefeliciteerd je hebt (3/3) easter egg gevonden!");
 }

  for (pin; pin < 6; pin++)
  {digitalWrite(ledpins[pin], HIGH);
   delay(tijd);
   digitalWrite(ledpins[pin], LOW);}
  //loop voor volgorde heen. 

  for (pin1; pin1 < 6; pin1++)
  {digitalWrite(ledpins[pin], HIGH);
   delay(tijd);
   digitalWrite(ledpins[pin], LOW);}
  //loop zelfde volgorde terug
}
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is a poor problem description. We have to search your code for the possible problem and that get's way easier, when you give us a good description of the problem. So please answer the questions: What is actually happening depending on your actions? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: I agree with chrisl; however one problem I see is that you need to debounce the buttons, see https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Debounce   … also try to write your comments and variable names in English, not Dutch (I understand since I'm Dutch too, but most people will not).

Comment: thank you guys for the comments. I changed it according to you guys feedback.

Comment: Can you also give us a sample of the Serial output (if there is any)?

Comment: Why do you have one button with internal pullup but the other not?

Comment: I have no serial output :/, and i have one button with the pullup because i was searching for a sketch to make a pressed button function. I tested the sketch itself and it was working so i tought merging it together with this project then it should work aswell.

Comment: One button has no connection to ground. Check that purple wire second from the right on the top half of the breadboard...

Comment: At which point in the program do you update `timerdruktijd` if the button you mean is pressed (which of the buttons should even be pressed to activate this)?